# Moving from static site to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirects

I'm moving a site from static to Wordpress where all the pages in the old site were XXX.html.  This has gone ok as I included a Wordpress plugin to handle the renaming of pages/posts to .html.  I was wondering what I should do with pages that I don't plan to migrate.  For example I combined their old location and contact pages into one page in Wordpress.  I'd like to redirect the old location page to the new page on Wordpress.  Is there a plugin for that?  I wasn't able to find something or I was searching the wrong way.  I read others suggest using 301 redirects, is that the best way?  Thanks!

Comment: If you don't have access to the server root the [rewrite control plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-htaccess-control/) will allow you to modify the htaccess file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using 301 redirect statement in .htaccess file is the best way (on Linux hosts).

Add the below statement in the .htaccess file in your WordPress installation's root folder.

```
Redirect 301 /location.html http://www.yourdomain.com/contact.html
```

Replace these names with actual names from your site:
location.html
www.yourdomain.com
contact.html

BTW, you don't need a plugin to handle the renaming of pages/posts to .html. You can set this up by setting the -
Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks > Custom Structure
to:
/%postname%.html/

I wouldn't recommend using a plugin for these simple requirements.